# Print 3, 4 and 5 line of the file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I have a problem with a Linux command. I have to put on the output 3, 4 and 5 line of the file */etc/passwd*, but I have no idea how to do it. I can print first five line:

```
head -n 5 /etc/passwd
```

but I don't know how to remove first two lines or do all from scratch.

Comment: You could do `head -5 /etc/passwd | tail -3`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '3,5p' /etc/passwd
```

or

```
sed -n '3,5p;6q' /etc/passwd
```

(The second version would quit upon encountering line 6 so it would be efficient for huge files.)

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==3,NR==5' /etc/passwd
```

or

```
awk 'NR>=3{print}NR==5{exit}' /etc/passwd
```

(The second variant quit after printing line 5 so it's more efficient.)

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if $.>=3 and $.<=5;' /etc/passwd
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print if $.>=3; last if $.>5' /etc/passwd
```

(The second variant is, again, more efficient.)

---

For fun, lets time these different approaches on an input of 10 million lines:

```
$ time seq 10000000 | sed -n '3,5p'
3
4
5

real    0m10.086s
user    0m9.173s
sys     0m0.101s

$ time seq 10000000 | sed -n '3,5p;6q'
3
4
5

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.001s

$ time seq 10000000 | awk 'NR==3,NR==5'
3
4
5

real    0m12.906s
user    0m11.475s
sys     0m0.134s

$ time seq 10000000 | awk 'NR>=3{print}NR==5{exit}'
3
4
5

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.010s

$ time seq 10000000 | perl -ne 'print if $.>=3 and $.<=5;'
3
4
5

real    0m15.982s
user    0m14.217s
sys     0m0.179s

$ time seq 10000000 | perl -ne 'print if $.>=3; last if $.>5'
3
4
5
6

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.011s
```

It's evident that quitting in case of large inputs once the desired lines are obtained is much more efficient.  On small inputs, the difference would be negligible, though.

Comment: You might want to quit after line 5 if performance is critical, but for simplicity's sake, we assume it isn't.

Comment: Yep quitting seems right but +1 for both versions none the less

Comment: @tripleee Right; quitting would help in case of large files.  Updated.

Comment: `awk 'NR==3,NR==5{print} NR==5{exit}'`?

Comment: @kojiro Thanks.  Added a comparison for an input of 10 million lines.

Answer (score 2):

Use tail:

```
head -n 5 /etc/passwd | tail -n 3
```

Tail returns the last lines of a file together with a pipe you can use both features.